# Problem with register form in php:laravel

Tags: php, laravel, forms

I am creating a game with `Laravel` that multi users can play it.i used `Java script` to submit users `forms` when something happened in `database`.

`Js` codes :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    var intervalID = window.setInterval(myCallback, 1000);

    function myCallback() {

        $.ajax({
            url: '/games/stop',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                room_id: 5
            },
            success: function (response) {
                if (response.success) {
                    document.getElementById("gameForm").submit();
                }
            },
            error: function () {
            }
        });

    }
});
```

`Html` form codes :

```
<form id="gameForm" action="{{ route('frontend.store') }}" method="post">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input id="game_first_name" placeholder="name" type="text"
           name="game_name">
    <input id="game_last_name" placeholder="last" type="text"
           name="game_last">
    <button type="submit">Stop</button>
</form>
```

`Laravel` codes:

```
public function stop(Request $request)
{
    $room = Room::find($request->input('room_id'));
    if ($room) {
        if ($room->status == Room::STOP) {
            return [
                'success' => true,
                'message' => 'reload'
            ];
        }
        return [
            'success' => false,
            'message' => 'error'
        ];
    }
}



public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $roomUser = RoomUser::where('status', RoomUser::ALLOWED)->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get()->first();
        $room = Room::find($roomUser->room_id);

        if ($room->status != Room::STOP) {
            $room->update([
                'status' => Room::STOP
            ]);

        }

        $new_paper = Paper::create([
            'room_user_id' => $roomUser->id,
            'status' => Paper::PENDING,
            'char' => $room->char,
            'name' => $request->input('game_name'),
            'last' => $request->input('game_last')
        ]);

        if ($new_paper) {
            return redirect()->route('frontend.open', [$roomUser->room_id]);
        }

    }
```

When one user submits her/his form, the rest of the users submit their forms automatically.

> **But the problem is** : Sometimes 2 of 3 or 1 of 3 or 4 forms submit or one form submit several times.

Any body can help me ?

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question, but this sounds also like a perfect scenario for websockets. Maybe take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/broadcasting and reconsider your design?

Comment: @wschopohl wow.Laravel do it for me ? check database every second ?

Comment: No laravel won't do it for you. But I guess, that some event - maybe from a user maybe not - will change an entry in your database. And when that happens you can use Broadcasts to push that info to all connected users. So there is no need to pull the database every interval!

Comment: Another comment on your error: Are you sure that your test scenario is working? How are you testing? Same computer, same browser?

Comment: @wschopohl Yes i sure because it works on localhost. but sometimes have problem.i am testing on a hotspot and a ip and all devices connect to ip.

Comment: Well if your sure your test scenario should work, than I would try to debug the process step by step. So for example instead of submit on ajax response just display an alert box on every device and see if that works. Also maybe you shouldn't work with setInterval but set a new timeout on every successful (or unsuccesssful) ajax request. This way they don't overlap if the server takes longer to answer ..